# Electron: How can I get Screen from BrowserWindow?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to know where `BrowserWindow` located from two or more screens. 
I guess Electron API doesn't give a method. How can I do that? Is there any way or something??

Comment: can you provide more info about what you want exactly ? thanks.

Answer (score 7):

There is no direct way to achieve this. But following can definitely serve your purpose.

```js
const {BrowserWindow, screen} = require('electron');

let window = new BrowserWindow();

// Load a URL and show the window first

const winBounds = window.getBounds();
const whichScreen = screen.getDisplayNearestPoint({x: winBounds.x, y: winBounds.y});
// Returns the screen where your window is located
```

This is tested to be working.

Comment: Tested locally, and only *almost* works.  Problem (on mac) is that your window may only show on one screen, but it's origin may be moved off the screen it's showing on.  I can reproduce my moving the screen until the left hand side is off the monitor, if only by a few points.

Answer (score 1):

For detecting which screen has your window inside, after you created your window:

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({...});
```

Using `Screen` API and `getDisplayNearestPoint()` method, you can get the screen coordinates:

```
const winBounds = win.getBounds();
const distScreen = screen.getDisplayNearestPoint({x: winBounds.x, y: winBounds.y})
```

And also, for if you want to get which screen has the mouse cursor inside, use:

```
let cursor = screen.getCursorScreenPoint();
let distScreen = screen.getDisplayNearestPoint({x: cursor.x, y: cursor.y});
```

Answer (score 0):

Electron defines a [screen](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/screen/) API which contains the screen.getAllDisplays() method returning an array of [Display](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/structures/display/) objects that are currently available.

I guess you would have to loop over the list of displays, get their bounds and check if they intersect with your window's own bounds. Or maybe use the workArea property? Unfortunately, I have only one display so I can't check how it would work...